# For some reason Output keeps telling me Invalid use of group function even when I'm not using it

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the code piece that shows the error idk why since Im not using group function

````sql
select concat('$',max(employees.salary)), concat('$',min(employees.Salary)), concat('$',format(avg(employees.salary),2)), employees.job
from employees
where avg(employees.salary) > 3000; ```
````

Comment: You didn't include the error message. What is that exact message?

Comment: errorcode: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aggregating by job, and then using the check on the average salary in the `HAVING` clause, not the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    job,
    CONCAT('$', MAX(salary)),
    CONCAT('$', MIN(salary)),
    CONCAT('$', FORMAT(AVG(salary), 2))
FROM employees
GROUP BY
    job
HAVING
    AVG(salary) > 3000;
```

Answer (score 1):

min, max and avg ARE group by components.  Your last column is the job.  So you need to have that as group by such as

```
select 
      concat('$',max(employees.salary)), 
      concat('$',min(employees.Salary)),
      concat('$',format(avg(employees.salary),2)), 
      employees.job
   from 
      employees
   group by
      employees.job
   having
      avg(employees.salary) > 3000
```